# After Angular.js $http request, call complete function regardless of success or failure of promise

Tags: ajax, angularjs, promise

How can I ensure that the `complete()` function will run regardless of the outcome of the $http call using the promise API provided with Angular.js?

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: submitUrl,
    data: $scope.data
})
.success(function(data) {
      // execute this code on success
})
.error(function(data) {
      // execute this code on error
})
.complete(function() {
  // execute this code regardless of outcome
});
```

One could use this to hide an AJAX spinner icon once the request is complete. You would want to hide the spinner regardless of the request outcome.

Comment: what do you want to acheive by this way ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm not the world's greatest expert in Angular.js but understand you can do as follows :

```
whatever.then(function() {
    // success code here
}, function() {
    // error code here
    return true; // return anything that's not undefined (and not a `throw()`) to force the chain down the success path at the following then().
}).then(function() {
    // "complete" code here
});
```

You are essentially forced to contrive something from one or more `.then()`, which is a $q promise's only method.

Comment: Makes sense. The second .then() is executed once the first is resolved or rejected.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on what you would like to do, but for clean-up logic and similar you may also use [`finally()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) to run either on fulfillment or rejection of your promise:

```js
promise.finally(function () {
    // Do something regardless of outcome.
});
```

Please note that although `finally()` is supported by `$q` (and some other libraries) is not part of the [official draft](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-operations-on-promise-objects).

Comment: this work  for me, i used to control the requests ajax finish and hide icon loading

Answer (score 8):

If you don't care if the request is successful or not, then you can pass the same callback to `success` and `error`...

```
   var cb = function(response){
      // do something
   };


   $http.post(submitUrl, $scope.data).success(cb).error(cb);

   // OR

   $http.post(submitUrl, $scope.data).then(cb, cb);
```

But be aware that `success` and `error` callbacks have a different signature than the `then` callbacks.

- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http
- http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q

Also, promises are recognized by the templating engine in angular, which means that in templates you can treat promises attached to a scope as if they were the resulting values.

This means that you can do this:

Controller:

```
$scope.article = $http.get('/articles/' + articleId);
```

Template:

```
<article ng-cloak>
   <h3>{{article.title}}</h3>
   <div>{{article.content}}</div>
</article>
```

And the view will update when the `$http.get` promise has been resolved.

Comment: I'll read into promises and the templating engine, sounds interesting.

Comment: Almost 1 year later, a quick note that promise (auto-)unwrapping in templates has been [removed in version 1.2.0](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/fa6e411da26824a5bae55f37ce7dbb859653276d).