# Is there a way I can track when there is a $http in progress?

Tags: angularjs

My service has the following:

```
self.$http({
   url:    xxx,
   method: "DELETE"
})
.success((): void => {

});
```

Is there a way that I can change the state of a button on my html to be disabled while the $http call is in progress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use flag and can call then method of $http. Set flag to true initially, and set it to false in then callback. i.e. the request is completed.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17181651/2034794) is a reference for similar question. But you cant check the completion percentage of ajax.

```
$scope.inprogress=true;//Ajax is in progress
self.$http({
   url: self.ac.dataServer + "/api/content/Delete/" + self.content.contentId,
   method: "DELETE"
})
.then((): void => {
//Success code here
},():void =>{
//Error handler code here
return true;
}).then(():void =>{
  $scope.isProgress=false; //Ajax completed
});
```

Comment: I thought of doing it this way but is there no flag that is set with the $http that does this for me?

Comment: No, this is the most common way to do this.